# Angular 5 ng2-loading-bar does not work correctly on firefox

Tags: angular, firefox, angular5

I used @ng2-loading-bar in my project.

```
"devDependencies": {
    .
    .
    "ng2-loading-bar": "0.0.6",
    .
    .
}
```

It works on Chrome, but it doesn't work on Firefox correctly.
The progress bar does not complete in Firefox.

```
import {LoadingBarService} from "ng2-loading-bar";

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

    constructor(private http: Http,
                private loadingBarService: LoadingBarService,
                private logger: Logger,
                private storageService: StorageService,
                private tokenService: TokenService,
                private router: Router) {
    }

    private sendGet(url: string, headers: Headers): Observable<any> {
        headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        this.emitStart();

        return this.http.get(url, options)
            .map(this.onComplete)
            .catch((error: any) => this.handleError(error, this));
    }

    private emitStart() {
        this.loadingBarService.start();
    }
}
```

any idea why the loading bar does not work ?

Comment: Can you provide an example on stackblitz.com or plunkr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has problem with ajax request in Firefox browser.
But you can simply use `loadingBarService.complete()` to complete the loading bar.
This function already exist and define in "ng2-loading-bar" package.

Comment: thanks :) After implementation of loadingBarService.complete() in error / success response, it works correctly.